# How to create a SharePoint 2010 list item by using a SharePoint 2013 workflow with REST POST?

Tags: 2013, 2010, workflow

I want to create a list item on a SharePoint 2010 Server Site by running a SharePoint 2013 Workflow using "Call Http web service" REST with POST method.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [Create an item with REST API from workflow - Sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138936/create-an-item-with-rest-api-from-workflow-sharepoint-2013/177784#177784).

Please go through this thread once.Let me know whether it helped or not.

Comment: I followed you suggestion but is not duplicated. The post there is to call a REST Service using GET in a 2013 environment. I want to use POST to create an item in a 2010 environment.